# git how to move files in the repository one step back

Tags: git, repository, git-push, git-commit

I am totally new to git and I can't figure out how to solve the problem. When I clone project from remote repository there's a duplicate ".git" folder in it and it looks something like: `repo/.git/trueprojectfiles(including real .git containing indexes)` my problem is that the git looks for index files in the fake .git folder and fails. As a result I can't do any changes to repository. How can I make repository to look like this: `repo/trueprojectfiles` and push the changes to remote?

Comment: could it be that you created `repo/.git` before you cloned and typed `git clone <whatever> .` while being in `repo/.git`?

Comment: As long as you didn't commit anything yet, delete the repo (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1213430/how-to-fully-delete-a-git-repository-created-with-init) and re-create it (http://stackoverflow.com/q/9864728/520162)

Comment: I just figured out that the directory is created when i run git clone command. are there any configurations to stop doing that?

Comment: yes, of course it gets created during `clone`. Did you read the 2 questions and their answers?

Comment: Wow, i cant believe it worked, I spent so much time on it trying everything. Thank you very much!