# How to integrate and work with complex structure GIT repository sync and stored in a folder in the PYTHONPATH

Tags: python, git, github, pythonpath

I have my github project `MYMODULE` structure following the guidelines e.g.:

```
README.rst
LICENSE
sample/__init__.py
sample/core.py
sample/helpers.py
```

The core of my project is inside `sample` folder where `__init__.py` is stored. 
I would like to be able to keep it accessible including `sample` folder in the PYTHONPATH, but of course if I `git -clone` the project in a folder listed in the PYTHONPATH I will have another folder `MYMODULE` before the `sample` folder with the `__init__` file, and so I won't be able to import it. I know that if I move the sample folder one level up I will be able to access the module but this will compromise the sync with my GitHub repository.

Is there any guideline or best practice for solving this issue?

I've tried to use git **sparse checkout** but this doesn't solve the issue because it however stores the folder selected inside a parent folder.

Comment: How about cloning into current folder? https://stackoverflow.com/a/46914108/5588279

Comment: `git` is a development tool but not distribution/deployment. To install a Python package you should have [`setup.py`](https://packaging.python.org/). Then you can install the package [directly from git](https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#vcs-support) using [`pip`](https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_guide/) or you can clone the repo yourself and install with `pip install -e .` or even with `python setup.py install`.

Comment: @Sraw that will clone all the project and I will have the same result

Comment: @phd if fact I am using git as a development tool and I want to develop my project inside the python path to be able to import it outside the project folder, I don't want to make a setup.py for a project in the earl phases

Comment: During development point `$PYTHONPATH` to the current directory: `export PYTHONPATH=$(pwd)`

Comment: @phd thanks but so I have to add a directory to export a for every project I do?  I would prefer to avoid creating so many system variables... I am not sure is a best practice

Comment: The best practice is [tag:virtualenv]. Create `setup.py` for every package, create a virtualnev for every separate project, install projects with `pip install -e .`

Comment: @phd thanks a lot  I've tried your solution with pip install -e I think is the only valid, can you formalize it with an answer for other users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git` is a development tool but not distribution/deployment. To install a Python package you should have [`setup.py`](https://packaging.python.org/). Then you can [install the package directly from git](https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#vcs-support) using [`pip`](https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_guide/) or you can clone the repository yourself and install with `pip install -e .` or even with `python setup.py install`

During development you can clone the code and point `$PYTHONPATH` to the current directory: `export PYTHONPATH=$(pwd)`

But the best practice is [`virtualenv`](http://www.virtualenv.org/). Create setup.py for every package, create a virtualenv for every separate project, install packages with `pip install -e .`