# Change local repo directory in Github

Tags: git, github, repository, github-for-mac

I have a Github remote repo and sync with my local repo. It's ok. But now, create a new directory and it's have last and true files.

How can i change my local repo via Git?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean. Why not just clone the repo to the new directory?

Comment: Clone overwrite old files to my new files?

Comment: Ah, now I got it. So you have an unversioned directory that has your "newest" files. See this question: [What's the best practice to git clone into an existing folder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5377960/whats-the-best-practice-to-git-clone-into-an-existing-folder)

Answer (score 0):

I did this for my windows OS.
Open the short cut link to GitHub.
Select Run.
Select the sprocket in the upper right hand corner.
Select Options...
On the right side you should see the Clone path.  Here you can Browse to the file path you desire.
I hope this helps and is what you wanted to know.