# .git folder disappeared, git status gives "Not a git repository"

Tags: macos, git, github, osx-mountain-lion, smartgit

I have been using a git repository on my MacBook Pro (OS X Mountain Lion) for several months. Mostly, I've been using the SmartGit client, but also command line. Today, I changed several files and went to SmartGit to commit and push, and SmartGit had "missing" by the repo name.

Using Finder, I confirmed that the working tree folder and subfolders were all in good shape.

On the command line, "ls -a" showed a .gitignore file but no .git folder in the working tree folder.

Tried "git status" and it gave:

> fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

I do have the same repository on a Windows machine as well, where it's working fine.  It's just missing those changed files on the MacBook Pro that hadn't been committed yet.

Suggestions on how to proceed?

Comment: I finally just re-cloned the repo from github into an empty folder and moved the few changed files into that folder.

Answer (score 8):

I suggest you `git clone` the repository from your Windows machine to a temporary directory (copying it should do as well), and then move the `.git` directory over to your original working directory.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13852329/6252399
This has a nice example on how to do this