# Clone Git repository to the current eclipse workspace by using EGit

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I use eclipse 3.8.2 and I've installed `EGit` plugin ver 3.6.2.
I'm trying to clone the projects from the remote repository into the current eclipse workspace by using `EGit` and I see a message notice me that

> "C:\Eclipse\Workspace\project is not an empty directory"
>    (because it's contain .meta-data folder).

So how can I clone the remote repository into the workspaces of eclipse while it's running ? (because I don't want to use the Git Bash to clone it before I start eclipse)

Thank in advance.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411031/how-do-i-clone-into-a-non-empty-directory and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5377960/whats-the-best-practice-to-git-clone-into-an-existing-folder

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your repository is already cloned (means there is a local repository under `c:\Users\username\git`

So, either you delete your project directory in your local repo and you clone like you did under eclipse

Or (preferred), you simply add your existing repo into your eclipse workspace with :

`Git repository view > Add an existing local Git repository to the view (Icons with green +)> Select your local repo > Right click on it > Import Projects...`

Comment: I have not cloned the repository in any where else, I just try to clone it to the current eclipse workspace by using EGit. Is there any possible ways to do it ?

Comment: You don't clone it in your eclipse workspace, you clone it in your your Windows user directory, then import it in your workspace. You also don't need to create a directory with the project name, it get created automatically