# How does `git clone` deal with any existing files and subdirectories in the target directory?

Tags: git

`git init` leaves alone any existing files and subdirectories in the target directory.

How does `git clone` deal with any existing files and subdirectories in the target directory?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the best practice to "git clone" into an existing folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5377960/whats-the-best-practice-to-git-clone-into-an-existing-folder)

Comment: I am asking what it does, not what is the best I shall do.

Comment: I did a quick test and it doesn't do anything `fatal: destination path 'test' already exists and is not an empty directory.`

Answer (score 0):

`git clone` refuses to clone into an existing, non-empty directory.  Therefore no problem can ever occur, except of course for the fact that `git clone` says **no**.

(Prior to Git 1.6.3 or so, `git clone` refused to clone into an existing directory even if it was empty.)