# How to add a remote git branch to local development folder?

Tags: git

*I am new to git so sorry if the question is dumb.*

I have a project called `helloworld` a branch called `newfeatures` which is not `origin` on github. My goal is to get all the files and folders into the folder in Eclipse directory I have specified we can call it `/documents/eclipse/java`.

What I did was that I install git then went into the development directory and typed

```
git init

git clone https://githuburlhere
```

I now have a folder called `helloworld` with a bunch of git-files but I don't see any java files from gihub. **How can I get the files?**

I have also tried

```
git pull origin newfeatures
```

But it said

> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
> exists.

Comment: a bunch of Git files? Do you mean the hidden folder `.git`? Can you see the files in Github?

Comment: @Raptor, yes its `README.md` and `.git` with the latter having a bunch of folders like branches, hooks, info, logs, objects, refs and files like config, description, HEAD, index, packed-refs

Comment: To clone a specific branch, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1911126/188331)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I clone a specific Git branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911109/how-do-i-clone-a-specific-git-branch)

Comment: So I tried it and it says: "fatal: destination path `helloworld` already exists and is not an empty directory."

Comment: WHat I typed was `git clone --single-branch --branch newfeatures https://github.....`

Comment: `git init` is for when you want to make a new repo "here" (the current directory). `git clone` is for when you want to copy a repo from somewhere else to "here" (a subfolder in the current directory). Pick one or the other, but not both. Note I may have misunderstood the question, and if I did, you likely want [one of the top answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5377960/184546).

Comment: You should execute the command in an empty folder. Also, there is no need to use `git init`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```bash
cd /documents/eclipse/java
git clone https://github.com/me/myproject
cd myproject
git switch newfeatures
```

If `newfeatures` exists on the remote origin side, it will be checked out locally.

Make sure to point your Eclipse workspace to `/documents/eclipse/java/myproject`.