# Installing a folder from github

Tags: git, git-merge, git-clone

I'm trying to install [a Rails plugin for Geany](https://github.com/dejw/geany-on-rails), which is files on github. The repository has a directory `/geany` which I have to merge with my own `~/.config/geany`. Now I could just copy the files manually, but I want to retain the link so I can update.  I had a look at both `git clone` and `git merge`, but I don't really know what to do with them.

How do I "merge" the two directories?

(Edit) Where I want to merge the files, on my computer, isn't currently a git repo. It's just files that the text editor `geany` will use.

The difficulty seems to be in the fact that it's not `/` that I want to merge, but the (contents of) `/geany/` folder.

Also, how will I update my files using git?

Comment: Is your `~/.config/geany` a git repository, or just some files?

Answer (score 2):

Something you might be able to try is to clone the (full) repo to a different directory on your computer (eg `~/github/geany-on-rails`), have a symlink inside your `~/.config` directory so `~/.config/geany` points to `~/github/geany-on-rails/geany` and drop your modifications into that directory.

Comment: Will this work if there are already other files in `~/.config/geany/`?

Comment: I'd suggest you move your existing `~/.config/geany/` out of the way, set up this new symlinked version, then drop in the files you want to carry over

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to find the comment option for your question to paste the following; but is this relevant to what you're looking for?

[How do I clone into a non-empty directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411031/git-how-do-i-clone-into-a-non-empty-directory/2484349#2484349)

Comment: I've seen it before submitting my question, but didn't really know if I should do it.

Comment: Since the folder I want to merge is a level deeper in the repo, I have no idea how to merge it, as opposed to in the previous question.