# Force git to install to a folder already occupied

Tags: git

How do I force git to stop complaining the folder I want to clone to is already full of other stuff?

I've looked online and there is no info.

Comment: Yet http://stackoverflow.com/a/2484349/6309 sounds like a good workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do what I do, which is a bit dirty, but works.

Firstly just `git clone` into a new (temporary) directory. Once the clone is finished, move the `.git` directory from the temporary directory *to the existing directory you really want to clone into*. Finally, delete the temporary directory you initially cloned in to. You may have to `git reset` to clear up the working tree, but that should be it.

I use this pattern a lot because at my work we use SVN as our primary source control, but I like to use git to manage my work-in-progress. After I checkout a project from SVN I use the above steps to copy my personal git repo inside, and everything works dandily.