# Pushing or committing the changes to private server

Tags: git, github, ftp

I have personal projects that I develop them on my local PC and upload them to server via FTP when I finish them.

I started using git and it is very good for me to track what I changed. But when I commit or push the changes I don't want to push or commit them to github or anything like that. I want to push them to live server. Which is my own dedicated server. Because while I work on the project I test it on my local PC and I believe that it should be live. Instead of uploading the files that I change via ftp is it possible to push them with git into my own server. Which is media temple dedicated server.

I also installed git into the server. I tried push the files to github first then tried to clone the repository from github and it only creates a copy of the folder(project name).

When I try to use this code on my live server

```
git clone git@github.com:username/projectname.git thewebsitedirectory.com
```

it says

```
fatal: destination path 'thewebsitedirectory.com' already exists and is not an empty directory.
```

Because I already have files in there. The files that I can't delete and those files are in .gitignore to be ignored. (Uploaded pictures)

How can I do this or should I use FTP?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use [git-ftp](https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp) which is just what I want.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

As per `git clone` documentation:

```
   <directory>
       The name of a new directory to clone into. The "humanish" part of 
       the source repository is used if no directory is explicitly given
       (repo for /path/to/repo.git and foo for host.xz:foo/.git). Cloning
       into an existing directory is only allowed if the directory is empty.
```

You might want to check this one instead then: [How do I clone into a non-empty directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411031/how-do-i-clone-into-a-non-empty-directory)