# How to push changes to Git repository from uninitialized directory

Tags: git, version-control, bower

I have a local copy of all files from some Git repository in a uninitialized directory, i.e. not tracked by Git (without **.git** in it) and I've introduced some changes to it. How do I push those changes to the remote Git repository?

These actions can describe what I mean:

1. `git clone … ./` *- repository cloned*
2. `rm -Rf ./.git` *- repository no longer initialized*
3. `vi ./somefile` *- some changes introduced*

#### In a more practical aspect:

I have a cloned directory of some library created by `bower` dependency management tool. I've introduced some changes to this library and now I want to push those changes to the master.

I'm looking for a smart way to re-initialize this directory with Git and to push changes as a single commit to the remote repository.

Comment: You can't. You *must* keep the .git directory in order to interact with other copies of the repository.

Comment: @Code-Guru Thanks for your response! I know it is possible to achieve this by re-initializing directory with Git. I'm just looking for smarter method of doing this. I will update my question to reflect this.

Comment: The smarter way would be to use git as it's intended.

Comment: @Code-Guru Git is used to acquire project dependencies by many package managers like `Composer` and `Bower`. It's accepted industry practice. I'm looking for a way to quickly introduce changes to this packages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm looking for a smart way to re-initialize this directory with Git and to push changes as a single commit to the remote repository.

Easy: initialize it somewhere else:

```
cd /path/to/somewhere/else
git clone /url/to/bower
cd bower
```

Then reference your old folder (where you did some changes) as the git working tree **while you are in the new cloned repo**:

```
git --work-tree=/path/to/old/folder add .
git commit -m "changes'
git push
```

See the [`--work-tree` option of the `git` command](http://git-scm.com/docs/git).

---

In theory, you could do the `git clone` directly in your old folder with [`git clone -n`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone.html):

```
cd /path/to/your/old/folder
git clone -n /url/of/bower .
```

(It might complain the folder isn't an empty one, in which case do the git clone -n outside, and move the .git folder in your old folder)

But I prefer keeping the old folder intact, and doing git-related operations in a separate clone.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'll give it a try on a first occasion )

Comment: The second option worked for me, although, is there a way to overcome this "directory is not empty" check? Thank you!

Comment: @SlavaFominII not really. You can clone (without any checkout), and move the `.git`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2484349/6309