# How to add GIT to an existing project on server?

Tags: git

I have project on localhost and on server. There is a working version on the server and I would not like to stop working my site.

On localhost I did:

```
git init
git remote add origin github.....
git add .
git commit -m "first commit"
git push origin master
```

How to safely add GIT to the server? I have SSH.

I know I can do `git clone` in a separate folder etc, but I would like to do it on a working application. It is possible?

Comment: You are looking to deploy a newer version of your project without stopping the existing app?

Comment: First, I would just like to connect GIT with the same version of the code as locally. Only then I want to send changes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I clone into a non-empty directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411031/how-do-i-clone-into-a-non-empty-directory)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `ssh` properly has been setup properly in your server. You could just put your public key into the `.ssh/authorized_keys`.

As for doing `git clone` on running application. You also could do that. Though I would prefer to set my code repository on different server with the server that is being used to host the application.

For reference. Please read git's [documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server)

Comment: But git clone is used in an empty folder.

Comment: You have done git init on the folder right? If you have done it. Then it should work