# GIT - Cloning in non-empty directory with checking merge conflicts

Tags: git

I have a directory on a debian server. 
I created a git repo I would like to clone in. This git repo is a clean version of this directory which not include all non-necesserary files to store on my repo.

So, I would like to clone files into this directory, BUT I don't want to erase files in common without a kind of "merge conflict" if needed.

I saw this solution on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411031/how-do-i-clone-into-a-non-empty-directory) :

```
git init
git remote add origin PATH/TO/REPO
git fetch
git reset origin/master  # this is required if files in the non-empty directory are in the repo
git checkout -t origin/master
```

But what I'm asking is, would this just replace existing files (On server) with the version of those files from my repo ? Or will it shows to me if there are conflicts ?

Thanks !

Comment: Don't do this !   save your work before
git reset origin/master    shoud be ok

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: git reset origin/master    shoud be ok (all your updates will appear in git status) but your work is not saved.
I suggest that you create a branch and do  a git status ;  git add <all new files + modified ones>; git commit ; 
Once you have your work saved in a branch look for things like git merge

Comment: Good solution, thank you !

Answer (score 1):

That procedure is partially, but not entirely, correct for your use case.  Consider this approach:

```
# ... in the local directory
git init
```

You mention that your local has files that shouldnt' be in the repo - and presumably aren't in the repo yet.  So create a `.gitignore` file that lists those files.  Then

```
git add .
git commit
```

Now you have a local commit with your current worktree state.

```
A <--(master)
```

Then

```
git remote add origin URL/OF/REMOTE/REPO
```

(Note that URL/OF/REMOTE/REPO could be PATH/TO/REPO, if REPO is on the local filesystem; but even then I generally use a `file://` URL.)

```
git fetch
```

Now you have access to the repo's history.  Maybe it looks like

```
x -- x -- x -- O <--(origin/master)

A <--(master)
```

Next step is to merge the changes from the remote.

```
git merge --allow-unrelated-histories origin/master
```

For files only on your local copy... well, you put them in `.gitignore` so they should remain untracked.

For files only on the repo copy, they'll be added to the merge result.

For files identical in both locations, the merge will auto-resolve.

For anything else, you'll get a standard merge conflict.

Once you've resolved the conflicts, you should have a working tree state like what you want.  Just so we have a clear picture, let's look at what happens if you complete the merge.

```
git add .
git commit
```

Now you have

```
x -- x -- x -- O <--(origin/master)
                \
            A -- M <--(master)
```

You could push that, so that `master` shows updates to match your local state (excluding the files you `.gitignore`d).  That will also make commit `A` part of the origin history, which you might not want.  So another option from here would be

```
git reset --soft origin/master
```

Your local change will still be in the index and worktree, but the commit graph will now look like

```
x -- x -- x -- O <--(origin/master)(master)

A -- M
```

So now you can re-commit.  `A` and `M` will eventually drop from your local repo due to `gc`, and will never be made part of the remote history; but by re-committing you do add the changes to the remote, to sync it with your local directory (other than the ignored files).

Comment: Thanks for answer, will try that