# Merging existing git repository with new one

Tags: git

I had a git repository hosted on GitHub. I recently switched machines and copied the files manually to the new machine rather than doing `git pull`, kind of forgot to do so. Now I made some changes and initiated a new git repository while adding the GitHub one as remote. I need to know how can I merge the two repositories i.e keep my commit history from the GitHub one and also keep my changes made to the new one? Thank you!

Comment: Push the changes from the copy back up to the remote, then pull down anywhere you want. You can also transpose any files you've changed from your copy to a checked out version, then commit those changes, but be sure to do this carefully as you'll stomp any edits that happened after you made a copy.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I clone into a non-empty directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411031/how-do-i-clone-into-a-non-empty-directory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are not too many changes (just a single commit's worth), this is really easy:

1. Clone the (original) repo from Github into a new folder. `git clone ssh://... newfolder`
2. Copy and paste all your files from the folder where you made your changes, overwriting files in `newfolder`
3. Make a commit in `newfolder` and push. At this point, your Github history is correct. Delete the old folder, name the new one whatever you'd like.

Comment: Thank you, I modified 4-5 files and can't believe I am this dumb, this didn't cross my mind!

Answer (score 2):

You just need to rebase your new branch with upstream branch. You can do this by setting an upstream branch for your new branch with `git branch -u origin/my_branch` (assuming the remote you added is called `origin` and you are currently on your new branch) then execute `git pull --rebase` to rebase your branch. After that you can `git push` your new commits on top of your existing commits on GitHub.

Comment: Thank you, this is the correct solution if you have a made quite a lot of changes in the new repository, this works perfectly fine then. I had only modified a handful of files, that's why I went with mkasberg's solution. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Since you have already set remote url you can either create a new branch  to store the changes and push it.Later you can merge the branches when necessary.
Or
Since you have created local repository and set remot-url  you can directly push to your repository after commiting.
Hope this helps.