# Merging downloaded git repository with cloned one

Tags: git, github, merge

When downloading(not cloning) a repository via github there is no `.git` folder. If you make changes to this repository and then realize that you want to merge it with a real repository, what is the right way to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I clone into a non-empty directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411031/how-do-i-clone-into-a-non-empty-directory)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The zip you are downloading from github has a comment which is a commit-id. [Find a way](https://www.google.com/search?q=zip%20show%20comment) to extract it. When you have the sha1, you know for sure which version you had when downloaded the zip. After it, you could just get a real git-repo and have it locally. E.g. try following steps:

1. Clone the real repo from github.
2. do `git checkout -b myZipChanges <commit-id>` of the sha1 you extracted from the zip comment
3. move `.git` folder into the repo snapshot you extracted from that zip.
4. Now you'll have right state in your working directory - do whatever you like as usual.