# bitbucket repository starting from /var

Tags: linux, git

I need to clone a repo that starts from `/var` to my local (Linux) machine's `/var`.

BitBucket repo: `/var/...`

I need to clone to my machine's `/var`

Since my local directory `/var` has other files, will cloning the repo locally to `/var` remove my already existing files and folders? If so, how could this handled carefully?

Comment: Thanks. I'm a couple of points from a bronze badge in git. Every little bit helps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git will not allow you to clone directly into a non-empty folder, which is for your benefit, especially if you want the safe approach.

The safe way to do this is to clone the repo normally, into wherever you normally clone your repos, like `/home/myusername/myrepos` or whatever. Then simply copy the files you want into `/var`. If you want, you can set up symlinks to point from under `/var` to the files in your repository.

I would **not**, under any circumstances, recommend removing `/var` and symlinking it to your repo (or deleting it and cloning over it). `/var/` is relied on by many processes on your system. Messing with it like that will cause you problems, pretty much guaranteed.

Another alternative is to set up `/var` as a git repo. This will only be possible if your repository is set up with the *contents* of `/var`, not the actual folder itself. If `/var` is in your repo, you will need to clone to `/`, and I *really* don't think you should do that.

**I do not recommend this approach either.** That being said, here is a similar question: [How do I clone into a non-empty directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2411031/2988730). The [answer relevant to you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18999726/2988730) recommends

```
cd /var
git init
git remote add origin YOUR_REMOTE_URL
git fetch
git reset origin/master
```