# link a local project to an existing git repository

Tags: git, repository, bitbucket

I am facing a problem with linking a local project to a git repository.

The problem started when i created a new folder with the same name of the `git` repository, then i ran `git clone` to get the source code locally. but what happened is that the repository downloaded and created inside the folder i created. so in order to run the application with the correct path, i cut the downloaded repository and i past it in the root and i deleted the main folder (linked to the master). now i made some changes in the applications and i want to link the folder to the git repository in order to push the changes.

as a result, i have a project and i want to link this project to an existing git repository.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I clone into a non-empty directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411031/how-do-i-clone-into-a-non-empty-directory)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+clone+into+non-empty+folder

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably the folder `.git` got lost during your cut&paste. It's an invisible folder.

Suggested approach to fix:

1. **Rename** the current project folder to `project-save`
2. Clone the project again. Make sure the folder structure is correct now.
3. **Copy** all sources from `project-save` into the new project. You should now see a lot of "Overwrite?" questions. If you don't, something is wrong. "Yes to All" is your friend.
4. Use Git to check that your modifications are there.
5. Commit your modifications
6. Delete `project-save` if you're sure that you got everything

Alternatively, you can use `git remote add origin <url>` to add `<url>` (replace with the correct URL of the remote repo) but that will fail when the `.git` folder was lost or has been corrupted.