# Total reset of a git repo back to clone state?

Tags: git, clone

I have a box with a repo, we'll call it upstream. I have another box that cloned it a long time ago, we'll call it local.

A lot of things could have happened to local, it could have branches, tags, etc. I want to reset local to be in the same state as if it was a modern `git clone`. I don't want to *just* lose the changes in the working directory, I would like the states to be the same all around.

There are [other solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2484349/124486)  to this problem (usually which use cloning into a temp, nuking .git and moving over it) but I'm wondering if there is another way to do that with just git. I would prefer not to have to have to redownload what I don't need.

Comment: What's preventing you from just cloning it anew from upstream? What part of the old local repo do you try to preserve?

Comment: The working tree, which in our case includes utilities that are vital to keeping the system in a consistent state. (I know it's not a good idea)

Answer (score 1):

First, undo any single-branch-ness or shallowness unless the new clone would have been single-branch and/or shallow (in which case *do* any single-branch-ness or shallowness, but do the shallowing at the end of the process).  Clean out any other nonstandard settings that accumulated in `.git/config`, other than ones you *would* have set manually in your `git clone` operation.

Then, if needed, rename one upstream / origin remote, removing all the others.  Suppose, for instance, you had intended to use the default `git clone` remote name of `origin`, but the existing repository uses `upstream1` for that and has a second remote `upstream2`.  Remove `upstream2` (with `git remote remove`) and rename `upstream1` to `origin` (with `git remote rename`).

Then, run `git fetch` on the remote name you are keeping, whatever that is, with the `--prune` and `--prune-tags` options.  The default is `origin` so if you're keeping the default you can just `git fetch -p` as this will mean `git fetch =p origin`.  (I'm not 100% sure what happens to the upstream setting of the *current* branch, whatever it is, if it was some other remote, so you might want to just run `git fetch -p origin` to be safe in all cases.)

This next step assumes non-single-branch-ness.  I'm not sure what `origin/HEAD` is when you use a single-branch clone of, say, branch `X` while origin's `HEAD` is set to `master`.  If you're not worried about single-branch-ness (or you never use `origin/HEAD`) none of this really matters anyway, but I'm trying to be complete here.

Now run `git remote set-head --auto` on the remaining remote, e.g., `git remote --set-head origin --auto`.  There's a slight race between the previous step and this one.  If the upstream Git that you would have `git clone`d is moving its HEAD around from branch to branch all the time, that's sort of inevitable: which `HEAD` you got from them would depend on *when* you did your `git clone`.  However, this will expose the difference between running `git clone` and running this sequence of commands.  If the upstream Git *isn't* moving its HEAD around, there is no race here: their `HEAD` is stable between the `git fetch` and the `git remote set-head`.

Now choose the one local branch name you wish to have.  Typically, in a fresh `git clone` with all the defaults, the one local branch you would have is the one they recommend with their `HEAD`, which is now copied to your `origin/HEAD` due to the `git remote set-head`.  So read that out (`git branch -r origin` for instance, or `git symbolic-ref refs/remotes/origin/HEAD`) to see which branch that is.  (It's probably `master`.)  Check out *that* branch name—this should succeed even if your Git has to *create* it—and make sure its upstream is set to the appropriate remote-tracking name (e.g., `origin/master`), changing it if necessary.  Use `git reset --hard @{upstream}` to:

- move it, if `git checkout` didn't create it;
- reset your index and work-tree

and then delete the others and use `git clean -dfx` to remove all directories and files that would not have been extracted from the initial `git checkout` that a `git clone` would have run as its last step.

You're now done, unless you wanted a shallow clone, in which case you may now need to en-shallow-ize your current repository.  You may optionally run `git gc --prune=all` to clean up pack files.

#### Summary, minus all the fiddling with single-branch and shallow and such

If we can make a few reasonable assumptions the processes gets a lot simpler.  The assumptions are:

- no single-branch-ness, no shallowness, and just one remote `origin` that's already set correctly;
- no *local* branches named `origin/*` to trip you up below;
- no other screwy local settings to clean up (e.g., you didn't `git config user.name` in this repository); and
- no desire to fuss with `git remote set-head` (you can do that any time though).

In this case, the process is this, which is pretty much cut-and-paste-able, just change `master` to whatever branch you wanted to keep:

```
git fetch -p --prune-tags
git checkout master             # or whatever branch you intended to keep
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master  # use correct origin/ name here
git reset --hard origin/master  # update work-tree
git clean -dfx                  # remove non-committed stuff from work-tree
git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short)' refs/heads |
    while read name; do
        [ "$name" == "master" ] && continue   # skip the one to keep
        git branch -D "$name"                 # delete the others
    done
```

(the above is untested, so be careful!).  The `--set-upstream-to` step is typically unnecessary (it will be a no-op), but I included it for completeness.

**Please note that the `git clean -dfx` step potentially removes a lot of potentially-useful files.**  You said you wanted the state you'd have if you ran `git clone`, though, and none of those potentially-useful files would be copied *by* `git clone`.  Since [you are probably doing this to *avoid* this particular `git clean` type of effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55418976/total-reset-of-a-git-repo-back-to-clone-state#comment97557775_55418976), you probably want to omit, or at the least modify a lot, the `git clean` step.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command to see your very first commit and it's hash:

```
git log --pretty=oneline | tail -1
```

Then run this command to reset to that hash:

```
git reset --hard [commit hash]
```

Comment: This points to the very *last* commit. Did you mean `tail` instead of `head`?

Comment: RomainValeri, you're right, I did, I've edited my post.

Comment: This doesn't delete remotes, branches and tags that I create.