# How to sync project from Github to Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, git, github

I have a Eclipse java project ( let's call it project X ) developed in computer A, then I push it to github ( only java files and some properties files). I didn't upload .project file of eclipse because I might want to work with it in another computer B. So in computer B I created a blank project with the same name X. When I try to fetch the java files from Github, it complains "there are already some files in the directory" and refuse to download. What did I do wrong and what is the right way to code across different computer with help of Github? Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411031/how-do-i-clone-into-a-non-empty-directory

Answer (score 0):

Try first to clone in a new empty folder.

*Then* add your new files in the cloned repository.

That way, Git will accept the first step (clone) without complaining it could overwrite existng files.