# How to add existing git repo to existing installation of same codebase

Tags: git

I have a non-version controlled directory containing a codebase.
I have the same codebase in git.

How can I introduce git in that directory without changing any of the files.
I'd like to see all differences as unstaged changes.

I suppose I can clone the git repo to another directory and move the .git subdirectory but I wonder if there are git commands to do this directly

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18999726/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+clone+into+non-empty+directory

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 2):

Initialise a `git` repository in that folder, add and fetch the remote, and do a diff:

```
$ git init
$ git remote add origin ...
$ git fetch origin
$ git diff origin/master
```

(the last command assumes your default branch is master)

Comment: You certainly can do this, but you probably want to create a `main` or `master` pointing to `origin/main` or `origin/master` and then do a `git read-tree` from that commit, after the `git fetch` and before the `git diff`.

Comment: or, as an alternative to torek, run `git checkout -b someName; git reset origin/someName`