# Clone a Git repo using Flutter/Dart

Tags: flutter, git, directory, process

I want to do a `Process.start('cmd', ['/c', 'git', 'clone', repoLink, selectedDirectory])` in flutter/dart.
My target directory is not empty because when I do a normal git clone, it creates a new folder with the name of the repo an clone inside that.
but when I pass the target folder to `git clone` command, it raise an error:

```
fatal: destination path 'd:\w' already exists and is not an empty directory.
```

And when i get the repo name and make a directory and add it to selectedDirectory, it would create another folder inside that with the exact same name.like: `D:\w\repoName\repoName\[repo files]`

So, how can I properly clone a git repo using Process in flutter?

**More information:**

My target directory is like:

```
D:\w\
  project1\
  project2\
  ...
```

In a normal clone case, you can simply cd to the target directory `D:\w` and do a `git clone <repo link>` while the target directory can be not empty.

but when you want to clone that repo while I am in a different path, git gives fatal error:

```
// git clone <repo-link> <target_folder>
C:\> git clone https://github.com/uesr/repo.git d:\w
fatal: destination path 'd:\w' already exists and is not an empty directory.
```

I have tried to get the repo name and make a directory and add it to selectedDirectory, but doing that, git clone will create another folder with the repo name.
I want to clone into `d:/w/repoName/[repo files]`

I would like to do this using Process and work with the actual git software that is installed on the machine.

Comment: Try `git -C selectedDirectory clone repoLink`; see [`git -C`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt--Cltpathgt).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I clone into a non-empty directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411031/how-do-i-clone-into-a-non-empty-directory)

Comment: Thank you @phd . I did not know about git -C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could do it using this process:

```
Process.start('cmd', ['/c', 'cd', selectedDirectory, '&', 'git', 'clone', repoLink])
```

I could not add multiple lines to execute after each other but you can use & to do so for one line commands.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [rw_git](https://pub.dev/packages/rw_git) which offers support for `clone` and other commands. You could write something like:

```
import 'package:rw_git/rw_git.dart';

...

RwGit rwGit = RwGit();
String localDirectoryToCloneInto = _createCheckoutDirectory(localDirectoryName);
bool clonedSuccessfully = rwGit.clone(localDirectoryToCloneInto, repositoryToClone);
```

It also offers various others commands that you might find useful.